# Using the googleDrive package in R, how can you trigger a sheet to 'recalculate'

Tags: r, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am using the [googleDrive](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googledrive/googledrive.pdf) package to write some data from R to my Google Drive, let's say Sheet 1.

I have a second google sheets, let's say Sheet 2, which imports data from various other sheets, among which Sheet 1. Now I 'just' want this Sheet 2 to recalculate whenever I upload new data to Sheet 1, which would mean that the new data from Sheet 1 also gets imported into Sheet 2. I wonder what would be the easiest way to do this? Is there perhaps a way to simply prompt a re-evaluation of a sheet from within R?

Comment: Does it need to be programmaticaly? You can insert into the second sheet the cell formula [=IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en), so that Sheet 2 will always automatically update whenever there are updates in the imported range (Sheet 1).

Comment: please edit your question include your code and describe what issues you are having with your code.

Comment: @ziganotschka, I am indeed using this solution right now with automatic recalculation in my main Sheet 2. It does the job, but was indeed wondering what the most elegant way would be to do recalculation programmatically.

Comment: @DaImTo I don't have any issues with current code I could share... I am wondering whether there is any existing functionality that prompts a Google Sheet to recalculate.

Comment: Apps Script features triggers, e.g. `onEdit`, but they do not fire an programmatic edits, see [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions). So in this case `=IMPORTRANGE` might be a more elegant solution than a script.

Comment: Thanks @ziganotschka. Just as a final question; the =IMPORTRANGE function by default updates whenever there is a change in the target sheet or should I address this in the sheet settings?

Comment: It automatically updates wherever there is a change in the range to watch (the one specified as `range_string`)